# Add class in kartik gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2

How can i add class in kartik gridview?

[image]

i want is to add pull-right to move the pagination to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pager options like this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'pager' => ['options' => ['class'=> 'pagination pull-right']],
```